# Keycloak 18 change user password and email

Tags: java, keycloak

I need to allow users to change their email address and password directly from my application.

Is it possible to implement this with the following Java library?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>18.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Could you please show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function from UserResource class to reset the selected user password

[resetPassword​(CredentialRepresentation credentialRepresentation)](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/admin/client/resource/UserResource.html#resetPassword(org.keycloak.representations.idm.CredentialRepresentation))

As you can see it takes on CredentialRepresentation, that is the class in which you need to instantiate the object to hold the credential information so that keycloak can use.